# Indexing using a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use a Targmax tensor to index a tensor.

In numpy you can do the following indexing:

```
mat = np.random.uniform(size = 3*10*10).reshape((3,10,10))
indices = [np.array([0,0,1,2]),np.array([1,1,2,3]), np.array([1,3,0,3])]
mat[indices]
```

Is there an equivalent operation in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.gather_nd(x,[[0,0],[1,1]]))
```

Out

```
array([1, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: PS: the bug for further feature parity with numpy indexing is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206